# Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'details.id' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, cakephp, elasticsearch

Im using cakephp-elasticsearch plugin to index and search mysql Db. I followed the tutorial from this link:

```
https://github.com/dkullmann/CakePHP-Elastic-Search-DataSource
```

I have created the "details" module:

```
<?php
class details extends AppModel {

   public $useDbConfig = 'index';
public $useType = 'details';

    public $_mapping = array(
        'name' => array('type' => 'string'),
        'addr' => array('type' => 'string'),
        'phno' => array('type' => 'string'),
        'city' => array('type' => 'string'),
        'state' => array('type' => 'string'),

    );

    public function elasticMapping() {
        return $this->_mapping;
    }
}
?>
```

To start indexing records I used this command:

```
Console/cake Elastic.elastic index details
```

Im getting the following error:

```
Retrieving data from mysql starting on 1970-01-01 00:00:00
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'details.id' in 'field list'
#0 /var/www/cakephp/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php(460): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/cakephp/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php(426): DboSource->_execute('SELECT `details...', Array)
#2 /var/www/cakephp/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php(669): DboSource->execute('SELECT `details...', Array, Array)
#3 /var/www/cakephp/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php(1080): DboSource->fetchAll('SELECT `details...', false)
#4 /var/www/cakephp/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(2696): DboSource->read(Object(details), Array)
#5 /var/www/cakephp/app/Plugin/Elastic/Console/Command/ElasticShell.php(288): Model->find('all', Array)
#6 /var/www/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/Shell.php(389): ElasticShell->index()
#7 /var/www/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(200): Shell->runCommand('index', Array)
#8 /var/www/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(68): ShellDispatcher->dispatch()
#9 /var/www/cakephp/app/Console/cake.php(37): ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
#10 {main}
```

I dont have any field named id.. What mistake i would have done? Please help me!!

Answer (score 1):

### All db tables require a primary key

And by default, the name of that field is `id`. If the table has a different primary key it's required to set the [primaryKey](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#primarykey) property so that Cake knows what it is:

```
class MyModel extends AppModel {

    $primaryKey = 'odd';

}
```

### Be conventional

> What mistake i would have done?

There are other mistakes in the code in the question, namely:

#### Model names are singular

So, `class details` -> `class detail`.

Cake automatically uses the plural underscored form (`details`) when looking for the table to use.

#### Class Names are CameBacked

So `class detail` -> `class Detail`

There is more information about [CakePHP's conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html) in the book.

This is also implicitly reinforced in the documentation for the [ES plugin](https://github.com/dkullmann/CakePHP-Elastic-Search-DataSource#index-a-few-records), compare the cli call in the question:

```
Console/cake Elastic.elastic index details
                                   ^ lower case plural model name
```

With the one in the ES plugin readme:

```
Console/cake Elastic.elastic index Contact
                                   ^ Correct case and singular
```

Not following conventions is an easy way to find inconsistent behavior.

Comment: Thank you very much. I made changes as per your instructions. but When I run this command Console/cake Elastic.elastic index Detail Im getting following error:Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Detail.modified' in 'where clause'

Comment: `By default IndexableBehavior will declare your "modified" field as the field which tracks when each record was updated or created in order to synchronize it with ElasticSearch.` I suggest reading the readme ;). Good luck.